# SpeechLMBuilder.exe console output capturing

Tags: java, redirect, stream, capture

I am using Microsoft Dictation Resource Kit (DRK) to create custom language models for use by the MS speech recognition. The SpeechLMBuilder.exe is a program that is provided with the kit. While all the examples of use are from the command-line, I would like to use SpeechLMBuilder in scripts and eventually in a GUI application for a more generalized use.

I can successfully capture some console information, but not all -- e.g. I can capture and redirect STDOUT and STDERR to files of my choosing.

However it appears that the SpeechLMBuilder.exe writes certain information directly to the console and it becomes visible only when run from command-line.

For example lines, like:

> STATUS:Beginning Comp LM process
>   STATUS:Successfully loaded engine files, beginning merge of models
>   STATUS:Loading both models
>   STATUS:Loading input file:
>   STATUS:Reading unigrams...
>   STATUS:bigrams...
>   STATUS:trigrams...
>   STATUS:done.
>   STATUS:Loading input file:
>   STATUS:Reading unigrams...
>   STATUS:bigrams...
>   STATUS:trigrams...
>   STATUS:done.

I have tried to redirect handles 3 through 9 that Microsoft mentions at http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true as well, but nothing gets written there...

Any ideas?